# React Toolkit Query - How to use transformResponse props with injectEndpoints()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a root API where I am injecting endpoints. But when I try to add a transform function it doesn't work. [From the documentation of transformResponse](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#examples---transformresponse) I can see that the transform prop is attached to the query object.

#### Here is what I am trying

```
const departmentsApi = onboardApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getDepartments: builder.query({
            query: params => ({
                url: `departments`,
                params,
                // Transform and normalize API response
            }),
            transformResponse: response => {
                 console.log('transform', response);
                 return response;
            },
            providesTags: result => {
                return result
                    ? [
                            ...result.items.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Department', id })),
                            { type: 'Department', id: 'LIST' },
                      ]
                    : [{ type: 'Department', id: 'LIST' }];
            },
        }),
    }),
    overrideExisting: false,
});
```

Any guidance will be helpful.

#### Resources

1. [Documentation for Injecting endpoints](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You linked the docs of Redux-Query above, not RTK-Query. `transform` is not a thing. You probably want [`transformResponse`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-query-responses-with-transformresponse):

```js
getDepartments: builder.query({
    query: params => ({
        url: `departments`,
        params,
        // Transform and normalize API response
        transform: response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        },
    }),
    transformResponse: (response) => response.some.deeply.nested.collection,
    providesTags: result => {
        return result
            ? [
                    ...result.items.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Department', id })),
                    { type: 'Department', id: 'LIST' },
              ]
            : [{ type: 'Department', id: 'LIST' }];
    },
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to eh answer from @phry in certain situations you might wana use [queryFn](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-queryfn)

Lets say all your query received array of userIds, but your GET endpoint needs those usersIds as part of URL params in string. And in such case you will need to use `queryFn` and at the same time you cannot use `transformResponse` but still want to transform the result.

Then you can transform your data as following:

```
getDepartments: builder.query({
    async queryFn (arg, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) {
        if (arg.userIds.length === 0) {
          return { data: [] }
        }

        const response = await baseQuery({
          url: '/users',
          params: ({ userIds: arg.userIds.join(',') })
        })

        if ('data' in response) {
          return {
            data: response.data.map(item => ({
              ...item,
              // transform here
            }))
          }
        }

        return response as { data: GetApiResponse } | { error: { status: string, data: unknown } }// typescript type
      },
    providesTags: result => {
        ...
    },
}),
```

Comment: what could be the reason that you cannot use transformResponse?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim typescript type works better like this